# Procedural toothpaste texture on beveled curve

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shaders, shader-nodes

Imagine drawing with colored toothpaste.
If you rotate the tube around its own axis while drawing the path, the texture is simple like this:
[image]

But if you hold the tube in a fixed position while drawing,
the texture should twist in a way that reflects the direction of the underlying path
Like so: (wrongly simulated by rotating z axis of mapping node)
[image]

How do I do that, what's the approach here?
Should work on any path, see 'complex_path' object in example file.
[image]

Just another visual example of the effect in 2D.
Using a 2 colored brush texture you get black on the left side and red on the right side and all halftones inbetween.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question (the toothpaste rotation example is confusing). If you just want to twist the curve you can change its *Tilt* value. I would do this with GN along the spline. Example: https://imgur.com/a/bnVnC4V Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: So simple, curve tilt is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.